# Php Problem with mysql_query()

Tags: authentication, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I've been having problems with my php code. I seem to be getting an error from `@mysql_query()`.

Here's my code for php:

```
<?php
// A simple PHP script demonstrating how to connect to MySQL.
// Press the 'Run' button on the top to start the web server,
// then click the URL that is emitted to the Output tab of the console.

$servername = getenv('IP');
$username = getenv('C9_USER');
$passwordp = "";
$database = "game_database";
$dbport = 3306;

// Create connection
mysql_connect($servername, $username, $passwordp, $dbport)or die("Cant Connect to server");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Cant connect to database");
// Check connection


$Email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
$Password= $_REQUEST["Password"];

if (!$Email || !$Password){
echo"Email or password must be used";
}
else{
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE Email = '"  . $Email ."'";
$result_id = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Database Error");
$Total = mysql_num_rows($result_id);
if ($Total){
    $datas = @mysql_fetch_array($result_id);
    if (strcmp($Password, $datas["Password"])){
                $sql2 = "SELECT Characters FROM users WHERE Email = '" . $Email ."'";
                $result_id2 = @mysql_query($sql2) or die("Database Error!!!");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_id2)){
                    echo $row ["Characters"];
                    echo ":";
                    echo "Success";
                }
    }
    else{
        echo "WrongPassword";
    }
    }else {
        echo "NameDoesNotExist";
    }
}

?>
```

Here's my code for C#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LoginScript : MonoBehaviour {
#region Variables
//Static Variables
public static string Email = "";
public static string Password = "";
//Private Variables
private string createAccountUrl = "https://credmanager-rowanharley.c9.io/createaccount.php";
private string loginUrl = "https://credmanager-rowanharley.c9.io/loginaccount.php";
private string ConfirmPass= "";

private string CreateEmail = "";
private string CreatePassword = "";
//Public Variables
public string currentMenu = "Login";

//GUI test section
public float X;
public float Y;
public float Width;
public float Height;
#endregion
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    void OnGUI(){
        //If current menu is = login call login screen
        if (currentMenu == "Login"){
            LoginGUI();
        }
        //If current menu is = Create Account call CreateAccount screen
        else if(currentMenu == "CreateAccount"){
            CreateAccountGUI();
        }
    }
    //This method will login to accounts
    void LoginGUI(){
        GUI.Box (new Rect (210, 15, 300, 300), "Login");
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (250, 275, 105, 35), "Register Now!!!")) {
            currentMenu = "CreateAccount";
        }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (370, 275, 105, 35), "Login!")) {
            StartCoroutine(LoginAccount());
        }
        GUI.Label(new Rect(225, 55, 290, 100), "Before Continuing you need to login or register.");

        GUI.Label(new Rect(215, 102, 100, 100), "Email:");
        Email = GUI.TextField (new Rect (330, 100, 150, 25), Email);

        GUI.Label(new Rect(215, 150, 100, 100), "Password:");
        Password = GUI.TextField (new Rect (330, 147, 150, 25), Password);
    }
    void CreateAccountGUI(){
        GUI.Box (new Rect (210, 15, 300, 300), "Register to save progress");
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (250, 275, 105, 35), "Back")) {
            currentMenu = "Login";
        }
        GUI.Label(new Rect(225, 55, 290, 100), "Register NOW!!!");

        GUI.Label(new Rect(215, 102, 100, 100), "Email:");
        CreateEmail = GUI.TextField (new Rect (330, 100, 150, 25), CreateEmail);

        GUI.Label(new Rect(215, 150, 100, 100), "Password:");
        CreatePassword = GUI.TextField (new Rect (330, 147, 150, 25), CreatePassword);

        GUI.Label(new Rect(215, 198, 122, 100), "Confirm Password:");
        ConfirmPass = GUI.TextField (new Rect (330, 194, 150, 25), ConfirmPass);



        GUI.Box (new Rect (210, 15, 300, 300), "Register to save progress");
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (250, 275, 105, 35), "Back")) {
            currentMenu = "Login";
        }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (370, 275, 105, 35), "Create Account")) {
            if (CreatePassword == ConfirmPass){
                StartCoroutine("CreateAccount");

            }
            else{
                Debug.Log("Both Passwords are not the same");
            }
        }
    }



    IEnumerator CreateAccount(){
        //this sends info to php form
        WWWForm CreateAccountForm = new WWWForm ();
        CreateAccountForm.AddField ("Email", CreateEmail);
        CreateAccountForm.AddField ("Password", CreatePassword);

        WWW CreateAccountWWW = new WWW (createAccountUrl, CreateAccountForm);
        yield return CreateAccountWWW;

        if (CreateAccountWWW.error != null) {
            Debug.LogError ("Failed to Create Account. Is Internet On? Is URL Correct? Error Message: " + CreateAccountWWW.error);
        } else {
            string CreateAccountReturn = CreateAccountWWW.text;
            Debug.Log("Successfully Created Account " + CreateEmail);
            Application.LoadLevel("MainScene");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoginAccount(){
        Debug.Log ("Attempting to login...");
        WWWForm Form = new WWWForm ();
        Form.AddField ("Email", Email);
        Form.AddField ("Password", Password);
        WWW LoginAccountWWW = new WWW (loginUrl, Form);
        yield return LoginAccountWWW;
        if (LoginAccountWWW.error != null) {
            Debug.LogError("Problem with Database. Error Message: " + LoginAccountWWW.error);
        } 
        else {
            string LogText = LoginAccountWWW.text;
            Debug.Log(LogText);
            string[] LogTextSplit = LogText.Split(':');
            if (LogTextSplit[1] == "Success"){
                Application.LoadLevel("MainScene");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press play from unity editor I get error: "Database Error" from @mysql_query() on $result_id.

Comment: Try to figure about if your queries gives an error or not, for making this you have to call mysql_error() function after mysql_query() call.

Comment: Try without '@' just mysql_query

Comment: Warning: The PHP `mysql_query()` function (and all other `mysql_xxx()` functions) has been **deprecated** in recent PHP versions, and will be removed entirely in the next release of PHP. You should not be using it. If you are just learning PHP and this has been recommended to you, then you need to find a better and more up-to-date tutorial. If you are working with an existing code-base, then your code need updating. Either way, you need to switch to using the newer APIs provided in PHP; ie either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

use query string as format like this

"SELECT `m`.`name` FROM `test`.`members` WHERE `name`=%s OR `id`=%d OR `sex` IN (%a)", "Evil 'injection'", 'NaN', array('male', 'female', 'both', 'other', "Alien quote'man"));